# How to get number of elements in a redis hash map?

Tags: redis

Assuming that `myhash` is like:

```
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> HSET myhash field1 "foo"
(integer) 1
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> HSET myhash field2 "bar"
(integer) 1
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> HGETALL myhash
1) "field1"
2) "Hello"
3) "field2"
4) "World"
```

How can I get number of `myhash` elements, that is `2`, from redis-cli?

I'm learning redis from [this tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/redis/redis_hashes.htm) but could not find my answer there.

Comment: Tutorials don't answer *all* questions, they're just tutorials. The documentation should be your go-to, and *first* go-to, for things not in tutorials. In particular, the Redis docs can be grouped by "major" functionality, like hashes: http://redis.io/commands#hash

Comment: @DaveNewton You are right in general. But in this case the answer is actually there, it just slipped my eyes!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `HLEN` command.  Taken directly from the documentation at [redis.io](http://redis.io/commands/hlen):

```
redis> HSET myhash field1 "Hello"
(integer) 1
redis> HSET myhash field2 "World"
(integer) 1
redis> HLEN myhash
(integer) 2
redis>
```